# Create side by side div without affecting each other inside main div

Tags: html, css

I want to ceate div like this but inside one div like A and D in one div and B and E in one div and remaining in other divs in html.

I have option to use bootstrap also and jquery too.

[image]

code demo:

```
<div class="main">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col">
        <table>A</table>
     </div>
     <div class="col">
        <table>D</table>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col">
        <table>B</table>
     </div>
     <div class="col">
        <table>E</table>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col">
        <table>C</table>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I have used Ankit's solution but div mixes with each other.

[image]

After give min-height it goes well:

[image]

I don't want to give min-height.

Comment: Show your code that you tried so far.

Comment: In addition it would be awesome if you tell us if you're planning to use bootstrap or you want to do it from scratch. Thanks!

Comment: @AlbertVilaCanela I have option to use bootstrap also and jquery too.

Comment: A/D in the same `div` and B/E in another one? Is there a reason for this? I don't think there is non hardcoded css solution for this.

Comment: Because I have a list to display side by side inside one div and that list could be from anything A or B or C or anyone so if it is possible to set css so please provide!

Comment: @aavrug now please see question I have add some code demo

Comment: @padhiyar There is no CSS solution. The only way to realize this layout is JavaScript or change your markup.

Comment: @padhiyar I was trying to achieve your exact requirement and I also know that fixed height for ```.col``` class was not acceptable that's why it took a little long. Now try the solution that I provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <style>
.div{
    width: 90%;
    border: 2px solid;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 5px;}
</style>
</head>
<body style="font:15px Verdana;">
<div style="width:10%;display: -webkit-box;">
 <div style="width:50%;margin-right: 5px;"><div class="div">a</div>
    <div class="div">b</div>
    <div class="div">c</div></div>
<div style="width:50%;">
    <div class="div" style="height: 75px;">d</div>
    <div class="div" style="height: 75px;">e</div></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but here you have fixed the height I don't want to fix the height as data come it should fill automatically.

Comment: There is no problem with this structure, here height is doesn't matter , because first he has divided to div , if you increase or decrease the height there is no problem

Comment: @Ankit I have used this solution and update my question please look into what should I do now?

Comment: @Naila I have used this solution and update my question please look into that now what should I do for this?

Comment: Solved just one thing I need to remove i.e. height because height overlap the divs in my case.

Answer (score 1):

The thing you are trying to do is called Masonry Layout.
The basic of it can be obtained as below :

HTML:

```
<div class="masonry">
   <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>
   <div class="item">...</div>
   ...
   ...
   <div class="item">...</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.masonry { /* Masonry container */
    column-count: 4;
    column-gap: 1em;
}

.item { /* Masonry bricks or child elements */
    background-color: #eee;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 0 1em;
    width: 100%;
}
```

SOURCE: http://w3bits.com/css-masonry/

Comment: Can you please refer my question again I have add some code demo is it possible with that code!

Answer (score 1):

Try this, hopefully this will help.

```css
.main {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 150px;
}

.row {
  float: left;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.col {
  width: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  flex: 1 auto;
  margin: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col">
    <span>A</span>
   </div>
   <div class="col">
    <span>D</span>
   </div>
   <div class="col">
    <span>B</span>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col">
    <span>E</span>
   </div>
   <div class="col">
    <span>C</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I got the solutions using Ankit's answer still thanks for the answer.

Comment: Great to hear that you got a solution. I just gave this solution because the above one was for fixed height.